# Difference between Response.Redirect() and Response.Write()

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

and

```
Response.Write("<script>location.href='Default.aspx';</script>");
```

Why someone will choose the second one?

Answer (score 2):

firsts way is to pass redirection instruction in http response to browser while second way will use javascript feature of browser to rewrite url in address bar. i think first way is good because if someone has js disabled second way will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect function first send to Server then identifying the web page that we need to navigate and again resend to client.There is a extra round trips will be happen in the case of Response.Redirect method. To avoid this round trips we can use Javascript redirection method.

which one to use is totally dependent on case to case basis

Answer (score 0):

`Response.write()` is just for writing content on the current page. Whereas `Response.redirect()` transfer request to a new page.